# elasticsearch mongoosastic count api and min_score

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

Who knows how can I use _count API from elasticserch in mongoosastic with node.js ? 
Also I cant query with min_score.

```
{
    min_score: 1,
    query_string: {
        query : query[ 'search' ]
    }
}
```

this query gives me an error

> [query_parsing_exception] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object, with { index=users line=1 col=11 }